# ASP.NET WebApi Action Filters and Dependency Scope

Tags: structuremap, asp.net-web-api, ravendb

In order to flush changes to RavenDB in ASP.NET WebApi I created the following Action Filter:

```
public class RavenDbUnitOfWorkAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public Func<IDocumentSession> SessionFactory { get; set; }
    
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var session = SessionFactory.Invoke();
       
        if (session != null && actionExecutedContext.Exception == null)
        {
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
        
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

To inject the `IDocumentSession` I created a custom `IFilterProvider` that loops through each filter and sets any dependencies using setter injection (StructureMap).

I would like to know how instances of `IFilterProvider` are scoped. Reading [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver) it appears Controllers are created per request.

Currently I'm explicitly scoping the `IDocumentSession` per request using StructureMap. The question is, if I instead rely on the `IDependencyScope` (that uses a nested container) would the same instance of `IDocumentSession` be injected into my Action Filter?

#### [Update]

Testing further it would seem that Action Filters do not use the same dependency scope as a Controller. I'd prefer not to have the code for flushing the session in my Controller however.

Comment: I don't have an asnwer, but this article talks about filters and DI http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html

Comment: @suing this is referring to DI in MVC. My question is referring to DI in ASP.NET WebApi. The two are quite different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you practicly answered your own question in [JabbR](http://jabbr.net), using `GetDependencyScope` extension method for the `HttpRequestMessage` should solve your problem:

```
var session = Request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(IDocumentSession));
```